# Android, get current activity using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

In Android I want to get currently topmost Activity name. Methods like `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);` is deprecated and `AccessibilityService` should be enabled by user. Thus I decided to do this via **RxJava**. Basically, I will have one Singleton class that will hold Subject. I will update this Subject when on Activity resume, and on Activity pause. Also I will subscribe to this Subject from my background services to get currently running Activity.

My question is, how should I synchronously get my current Activity name in background job.

Subject holder Singleton class ActivityTracker.class

```
public class ActivityTracker {
        private static ActivityTracker instance;

        public static synchronized ActivityTracker getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new ActivityTracker();
            }
            return instance;
        }

    public PublishSubject<String> currentActivity = PublishSubject.create();

}
```

VideoPlayerActivity.class

```
ActivityTracker.getInstance().currentActivity
        .onNext(VideoPlayerActivity.class.getSimpleName());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how should I synchronously get my current Activity
>   name in background job.

you shouldn't. You should always subscribe and get the name as part of he onNext. If you want to do so, you should expose the Subject asObservable, E.g.

```
   public Observable<String> getActivityName() {
       return currentActivity.asObservable();
   }
```

from the outside you can then do:

```
ActivityTracker.getInstance().getActivityName().toBlocking().first();
```

`toBlocking` will transform your `Observable` into a `BlockingObservable` and `first` will block the execution until the first item is emitted

I strongly suggest you to read the differences between the type of subjects. I would use a `BehaviourSubject` if I were in you

Comment: I tried using BehaviorSubject like this in ActivityTracker: `public BehaviorSubject<String> currentActivitySubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    public Observable<String> getActivityName() {
        return currentActivitySubject.asObservable();
    }` . But not returning anything, code just stops working after trying to get `getActivityName`

Comment: My `currentActivitySubject` is empty - not getting his first `onNext` yet. How can I handle this case?

Comment: well, you know the start activity, it is declared in your manifest. You can pass its name at creation name to the subject. E.g. public `BehaviorSubject<String> currentActivitySubject = BehaviorSubject.create(SplashActivity.class.getSimpleName());`, where the subject is a member of your `ActivityTracker`

Comment: OK, got it. Thank you very much.